# how to populate a UITableView on a button touch

Tags: ios, uitableview, button, populate

So I am building an application for the iOS and i have got it to calculate a bunch of things and display them on the screen, on an `-(IBAction)calculate`.
it also builds an incrementing array that would be a cut list. there is a blank `UITableView` that runs down one side of the view. i have it after the `viewDidLoad`. now when i push the calculate button i would like to populate this list with the incrementing cutting list. I can't find any tutorial or such to help me with this.

it only gives me errors when I put it in the calculate action.
so i have left it after the `viewDidLoad` and was hoping to populate it off the button touch.

Here is what I have:

```
// Customize the number of sections in the table view.
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [creeperArray count];
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:         (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView       dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Configure the cell.
[cell.textLabel setText:[creeperArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

/*
 <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
 // ...
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
 [detailViewController release];
 */
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tell your table view to `reloadData`.  If its delegate and data source are set up right, and `creeperArray` contains the things you want displayed, it should work.

(If not, you'll need to provide more details.)

Answer (score 0):

You have not given the code details regarding your UIButton action and the array.Anyways , you will have to assign the changing array to your creeperArray everytime the array changes and then reload the table .

Now , if the changing array is some another class you will need to define a property for the same and access it for some forward class where as for backward data flow you will have to use protocol-delegates.

If the array resides in the same viewcontroller as the tableview then u simnply need to assign the contents of changing array to creeperArray and reload the table.